# Array in string replace postgres and Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

So say I have a column:

```
myCol
------
[a, b, c]
```

I can see that when I am trying to insert into postgres, `[]` is invalid, is the easiest solution to just replace the array with `{}`.

So if I have:

```
str = "['a', 'b', 'c']
```

I can just do

```
str['['] = '{'
str[']'] = '}
```

And the insert `str` into postgres?

Comment: What is the column type? But no, that isn’t how you do a `gsub` or positional replacement in Ruby. If it’s a string column `[]` is perfectly valid (a string is a string). If it’s a JSON column a non-string array is still valid.

Comment: @DaveNewton There are also native SQL arrays (`'{a,b,c}'` or `array['a', 'b', 'c']`). The braces in the question suggest that this is what they're talking about.

Comment: How are you talking to the database? ActiveRecord? Sequel? Something else? That will determine the best approach for inserting a value.

Comment: @muistooshort Realized that after OP's dupe, but to my eye, it looks like the OP is going about this backwards and should convert the string to a real array and let the ORM do the work, unless they're targeting raw SQL :shrug:

Comment: @DaveNewton Yes, there are some missing pieces here and hopefully we can get them filled in.

Comment: @muistooshort thanks! I am using `ActiveRecord`. The type of the column is "string" but I guess we have the array bit set since PSQL works that way. 

What is the best approach for checking if the string is an array and then converting it to a PSQL array?

Comment: Where is this string coming from? If you're expecting it to be an array then you should convert it to a Ruby array and then hand that off to ActiveRecord.

Comment: @muistooshort Yes, expeecitng it be an array. So what is the command to actually convert a string to an array?

Comment: Sorry for going on but where is this string coming from? Do you know the exact format of the string? For example, what if one of the strings in the array contains `'` or `"`, how will those be escaped? Can you fix the source to give you an array instead? Or maybe fix the source to use JSON for interchange? This isn't just a matter of throwing out the brackets and splitting on commas, you need to the specific input format before you can reliably parse it.

Comment: "The type of the column is "string" but I guess we have the array bit set since PSQL works that way.". Do you mean its defined as `t.string "foo", array: true`? That actually creates a `text[]` column - [a native typed array](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/arrays.html).  In that case you don't have to do anything at all - the database driver handles it all for you and whatever your doing is most likely just doing more harm then good. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_postgresql.html#array